# How to pause until signal and not have C print?

Tags: c, signals

I'm guessing I need to call some function in my signal handler and I have no idea what it is

My program wants to sleep until it receives some kind of signal. So naturally I used `pause()`. Now it ran just fine when I sent my app `SIGUSR1` however I get a print out of `User defined signal 1` which is not what I want because I plan to send many signals and it will make the console unreadable. I tried handling the signal by writing `signal(SIGUSR1, mySignalHandler);` but now `pause()` no longer resumes after I receive the signal. Is there some kind of function I need to call from mySignalHandler?

Comment: You should not call functions inside the signal handler.  You set a variable inside the signal and check that variable from a loop inside your program.  Waiting inside the loop can be done with sleep(), as the signal wakes up the sleep.

Comment: Do you know **who** prints "User defined signal 1"? Please show us a [mre].

Comment: @thebusybee How wrong I wrote my code has nothing to do with the solution. Turns out executing raise in a thread doesn't actually send it to the main thread. It tried to handle it itself. All it took was Mathieu example to show me how to do it correctly and notice the difference between what he did and what I did

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default behavior when a program receive a USR1 signal is to terminate (see https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html, standard signal).

An empty signal handle will just do what you want: no message will be displayed.

```c
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>

static int s_got = 0;

void handler(int s) 
{
    ++s_got;
}

int main(void)
{
    signal(SIGUSR1, handler);
    while(1) {
        pause();
        printf("resumed %d\n", s_got);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

```sh
:~/so/pause$ gcc -Wall main.c
:~/so/pause$ ./a.out &
[1] 2286
:~/so/pause$ pkill -USR1 a.out
resumed 1
:~/so/pause$ pkill -USR1 a.out
resumed 2
:~/so/pause$ pkill -USR1 a.out
resumed 3
:~/so/pause$ pkill -USR1 a.out
resumed 4
:~/so/pause$ pkill -USR1 a.out
resumed 5
:~/so/pause$
```

Comment: Oh thanks. It appears that when I did raise in my thread it killed the thread and didn't send the signal to my app. I was quite confused why your example worked and mine didn't until a few minutes in

Comment: Hey Mathieu it seems like most of my questions are tough enough not to get any upvotes or answers (not this one tho). SO is saying I might get a question ban if I don't get upvotes. Would you mind upvoting a few questions that you think are good? https://stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans